# Data loading and str. Conversion error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, format

I'm trying to convert stings to float and integers and load data. It is giving me no attribute format error. Please see my codes and errors. Remember these codes are taken from prominent ML specialist, Janson.

```
# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())

# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
    Salary_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup

# Load iris dataset
filename = 'C:\\Users\\Tesema\\Desktop\\PYTHON\\PYTHON3\\Salary.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows and {2} columns').format(filename, len(dataset),   len(dataset[0]))
print(dataset[0])
# convert string columns to float
for i in range(3):
    str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# convert class column to int
lookup = str_column_to_int(dataset, 3)
print(dataset[0])
print(lookup)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bac32ee07342> in <module>
     27 filename = 'C:\\Users\\Tesema\\Desktop\\PYTHON\\PYTHON3\\Salary.csv'
     28 dataset = load_csv(filename)
---> 29 print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows and {2} columns').format(filename, len(dataset), len(dataset[0]))
     30 print(dataset[0])
     31 # convert string columns to float

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many brackets:

replace:

```py
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows and {2} columns').format(filename, len(dataset), len(dataset[0]))
```

with:

```py
print('Loaded data file {0} with {1} rows and {2} columns'.format(filename, len(dataset), len(dataset[0])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, after replacing with your code, it has produced the following errors:                                                                                   Loaded data file C:\Users\Tesema\Desktop\PYTHON\PYTHON3\Salary.csv with 13 rows and 4 columns:
['experience', 'test_score', 'oral_score', 'salary']

----------------

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'experience'

Comment: Ok, do now it's different error, different line. It's coming from here: ```str_column_to_float(dataset, i)``` where -I think you are trying convert to float string headers. So the solution would be either remove headers from the dataset eg. ```dataset.pop(0)``` before calling that function in the loop